# Android Studio emulator using AMD Processor (ARM EABI does not work)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

I'm attempting to use the `AVD` emulator which is built-in to Android Studio and having serious issues on my desktop computer which has an `AMD processor`.

I'm aware that I can't use the usual `x86` images due to lack of HAXM on AMD.

However, most questions posted suggest using an ARM EABI system image for the emulator. When I tried doing this, it took approximately 1 hour to boot and crashed immediately. Any suggestions?

Is AMD really that terrible for Android emulation?

Another alternative suggestion I read was to use Genymotion, but it seems it isn't free anymore.

Processor is an AMD X4750k http://cpuboss.com/cpu/AMD-Athlon-X4-750k

Comment: Genymotion is still free for Personal use, just register and download it. Don't get fooled by the Pricing page on their website because it omits this tier.

Comment: Using the emulator requires a lot of RAM. Using both, Android Studio and emulator requires even more RAM.

Comment: I have 16 gigs of ram. Is there something I should change in the device settings? Should I allocate more or less ram to the device? Also, I will give genymotion a try, thanks for the heads up.